# How to robustly disable core dumps in application code regardless of Linux distribution configuration

Tags: linux, memory, ubuntu

For sensitive application it is necessary to protect against sensitive data being written to disk on application crash. Some distributions (like Ubuntu) have daemons (apport, whoopsie) collecting crash information and sending data to distribution provider (Cononical / Launchpad tracker). What measures can be taken in application code to mitigate this risk regardless of any particular distribution?

In particular, would following be enough to disable core dumps on Linux kernel level so that distribution (like Ubuntu) will never even get core dumps?

```
struct rlimit limit;
limit.rlim_cur = 0;
limit.rlim_max = 0;
setrlimit(RLIMIT_CORE, &limit)
```

Comment: Also see [Asserts considered harmful (or GMP spills its sensitive information)](https://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2018/12/31/1)